# Why would points differ in two places for the same answer?

Tags: support, reputation

Clicked little icon at the top of the page and a drop-down showed a plus-two next to a question.  Clicked that and it showed an answer I posted, but next to it was a minus-three.  Without wasting bandwidth on whether I deserved it, why the discrepancy?

Comment: `1 upvote - 4 downvotes = -3 score, (1 upvote * 10 rep) + (4 downvotes * -2 rep) = +2 rep`

Comment: I'm getting bored of these "why is my rep like X" questions. Just see the FAQ.

Comment: So one number is for the answer and the other number is for me.  Thanks.

Comment: @bjb568: What's a FAQ?

Comment: @Robert Frequently asked questions... ?

Comment: @bjb568: We don't have those.  We do have a Help Center, however.  Unless, perhaps, you're talking about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), but finding the answer to the OP's question there seems like it would be a bit difficult.

Comment: @Robert [Um…](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfaq%5D+how+does+reputation+work)

Comment: @bjb568: You could have linked that in the first place, couldn't you?  Saying "Read the FAQ" is like six steps removed.

Comment: @Robert Still, people should know how to search.

Comment: @michaelb958: if that were offered as an answer, I'd be happy to check off that it actually is.

Comment: @WGroleau Answered. (Sorry about the wait!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those two numbers mean different things. The `-3` is the post's score - total upvotes minus total downvotes. The `+2` is the total rep change you've earned/incurred from that post - 5 or 10 points per upvote, -2 per downvote.

The fact that they're not even both positive or negative arises from the large difference between gain from upvotes and loss from downvotes; a question receiving an upvote and two downvotes (`+1/-2`) will score `-1` but supply `+1` rep to its owner.

#### end of tl;dr

This naturally leads to a straightforward system of equations for calculating vote counts from rep change and score. (Credit for a lot of the below mathematical rigour goes to someone else's Meta SE answer I fondly remember but can't seem to find...)

Basically, for answers:

```
10 u - 2 d = r
   u -   d = s
```

where `s` is score and `r` is rep change. (For questions, change the 10 to a 5.) So if your answer scored `-3` and brought you `+2` rep, that's

```
10 u - 2 d =  2
   u -   d = -3
```

Some simple algebra (or, alternatively, [just give it to Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10u-2d%3D2%2Cu-d%3D-3)) reveals that your answer got 1 upvote and 4 downvotes.

<sub>Can you tell I like maths?</sub>